# how to convert selected data to same length (shape)

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

I'm reading multiple .csv files as a panda DataFrame with the same shape. for some index, some of the value is Zero, so I want to select the values of each index with same shape and put zero value for the same index and deleting Zero to become a same shape:

```
a = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv("path_a",index_col=0))
b = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv("path_b",index_col=0))
c = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv("path_c",index_col=0))
print a,"\n",b,"\n",c
L = np.array(a.shape)
X = L[0]
d = a.index.values
a = np.array(a)
b = np.array(b)
c = np.array(c)
for i in range (0,X):
    xdata  = a[i]
    xdata1 = b[i]
    xdata2 = c[i]
    xdata  = np.where(xdata2==0,0,xdata)
    xdata1 = np.where(xdata2==0,0,xdata1)
    xdata1 = np.where(xdata==0,0,xdata1)
    xdata2 = np.where(xdata==0,0,xdata2)
    xdata  = np.where(xdata1==0,0,xdata)
    xdata2 = np.where(xdata1==0,0,xdata2)
    indexX  = np.argwhere(xdata==0)
    index1X = np.argwhere(xdata1==0)
    index2X = np.argwhere(xdata2==0)
    xdata  = np.delete(xdata,indexX)
    xdata1 = np.delete(xdata1,index1X)
    xdata2 = np.delete(xdata2,index2X)
    print d[i],"\n",xdata,"\n",xdata1,"\n",xdata2
```

```
     1980  1985  1990  1995  2000  2005  2010
ISO3                                          
AFG    0.0   0.0   3.8   0.0   0.0   9.8   0.0
AGO    2.0   0.0   3.0   4.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
ALB    0.0   0.2   0.5   0.2   1.3   1.6   2.7
AND    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
ARE    0.7   0.8   0.9   1.7   2.3   2.7   3.0
ARG    3.1   6.7   5.3  15.1  17.2  18.2  18.7
ARM    0.4   0.5   0.5   0.5   0.4   1.2   1.3 
      1980  1985  1990  1995  2000  2005  2010
ISO3                                          
AFG    2.5   0.0   0.0   4.7   0.0   0.0   0.0
AGO   13.1  14.9  15.8  16.4  16.9  17.6  18.1
ALB    1.4   1.5   1.6   1.6   1.6   1.6   1.7
AND    0.2   0.2   0.2   0.2   0.1   0.4   0.6
ARE    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
ARG    1.8   1.8   1.7   1.8   1.8   1.9   1.9
ARM    1.8   1.8   1.7   0.0   1.8   1.9   1.5 
      1980  1985  1990  1995  2000  2005  2010
ISO3                                          
AFG    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
AGO    0.0   0.0   4.7   5.8   6.0   0.0   0.0
ALB    0.0   0.2   0.5   0.2   1.3   1.6   2.7
AND    1.4   1.8   2.3   3.7   0.0   0.0   5.4
ARE    0.7   0.8   0.9   1.7   2.3   2.7   3.0
ARG    3.1   6.7   5.3  15.1  17.2  18.2  18.7
ARM    0.4   0.5   0.5   0.5   0.4   1.2   1.3

AFG 
[] 
[] 
[]
AGO 
[ 3.  4.] 
[ 15.8  16.4] 
[ 4.7  5.8]
ALB 
[ 0.2  0.5  0.2  1.3  1.6  2.7] 
[ 1.5  1.6  1.6  1.6  1.6  1.7] 
[ 0.2  0.5  0.2  1.3  1.6  2.7]
AND 
[] 
[] 
[]
ARE 
[] 
[] 
[]
ARG 
[  3.1   6.7   5.3  15.1  17.2  18.2  18.7] 
[ 1.8  1.8  1.7  1.8  1.8  1.9  1.9] 
[  3.1   6.7   5.3  15.1  17.2  18.2  18.7]
ARM 
[ 0.4  0.5  0.5  0.4  1.2  1.3] 
[ 1.8  1.8  1.7  1.8  1.9  1.5] 
[ 0.4  0.5  0.5  0.4  1.2  1.3]
```

this code works, but it is a tentative way and it isn't efficient when the number of data is high. Could you suggest me a more efficient way and how to select data based on the Min length index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is multiple all 3 arrays and then test it for not `0`, also is possible use loop by 3 arrays in list `L1`. Then is also changed logic - selecting values not matched mask instead `np.argwhere` and `np.delete`:

```
L = np.array(a.shape)
X = L[0]
d = a.index.values
a = np.array(a)
b = np.array(b)
c = np.array(c)
m = (a * b * c) != 0
L1 = [a,b,c]

for i in range (0,X):
    for arr in L1:
        xdata  = arr[i][m[i]]
        print (xdata)
```

If use pandas 0.24+ then better for convert to numpy array is use [`to_numpy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_numpy.html):

```
L = np.array(a.shape)
X = L[0]
d = a.index.to_numpy()
a = a.to_numpy()
b = b.to_numpy()
c = c.to_numpy()
m = (a * b * c) != 0
L1 = [a,b,c]

for i in range (0,X):
    for arr in L1:
        xdata  = arr[i][m[i]]
        print (xdata)
```

EDIT:

```
L = np.array(a.shape)
X = L[0]
d = a.index.to_numpy()
a = a.to_numpy()
b = b.to_numpy()
c = c.to_numpy()
m = (a * b * c) != 0
L1 = [a,b,c]

for i in range (0,X):
    out = []
    for arr in L1:
        xdata  = arr[i][m[i]]
        out.append(xdata)
    data = np.vstack((out))
    print (data)

[]
[[ 3.   4. ]
 [15.8 16.4]
 [ 4.7  5.8]]
[[0.2 0.5 0.2 1.3 1.6 2.7]
 [1.5 1.6 1.6 1.6 1.6 1.7]
 [0.2 0.5 0.2 1.3 1.6 2.7]]
[]
[]
[[ 3.1  6.7  5.3 15.1 17.2 18.2 18.7]
 [ 1.8  1.8  1.7  1.8  1.8  1.9  1.9]
 [ 3.1  6.7  5.3 15.1 17.2 18.2 18.7]]
[[0.4 0.5 0.5 0.4 1.2 1.3]
 [1.8 1.8 1.7 1.8 1.9 1.5]
 [0.4 0.5 0.5 0.4 1.2 1.3]]
```

Comment: thank you, but how can I differentiate **xdata** if I want to use them as an input data?

Comment: @water77 - One possible solution is create numpy array for each index value, check edited answer.

Comment: @water77 - Thanks, glad to help. Don't forget to accept the answer, if it suits you! :)